# Videoconferencing software make my system freeze

Tags: thinkpad, overheating

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Thinkpad T480s, which has already undergone the usual temperature threshold fix as of [lenovo-throttling-fix](https://github.com/erpalma/throttled).
My laptop freezes a few minutes into the call with both the Zoom and Vidyo clients (videoconferencing), and the only solution is rebooting (and if I rejoin the videoconference, the same will happen again).
It seems to me that the issue has to do with overheating, just by touching it...
Is anyone able to suggest a way to debug and fix this issue?

More details:

- I am using the 5.1.0-050100-generic kernel from ukuu
- I have had similar issues with Vidyo for years, on this laptop and on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon (2013/14 version)

Comment: If you use the kernel from 18.04 LTS version `4.18.0-17-generic` do you still experience the same freezing?

Comment: It has always happened. I did not immediately upgrade the kernel when I installed the system. I will try to test it again with `4.18.0-17-generic`, but it is rather unpredictable and thus difficult to test.